# Cleaning tefillin from Covid19 contact

Tags: tefilin, medicine, cleaning

If someone contacts COVID-19, then everything they touch has to be disinfected. This is normally done with a wet disinfectant. Are there any recommendations for how to do this for tefillin to avoid damage to the parshiyos and the blackness of the surfaces?

Comment: "If someone contacts Covid 19, then everything they touch has to be disinfected." My understanding (with the full admission that I am no medical or scientific expert) is that the virus does not actually live on most surfaces that long. Wouldn't you be able to just leave it out for a bit and let the virus die out on its' own?

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/28/briefing/coronavirus-hong-kong-minneapolis-your-thursday-briefing.html

Comment: but if you want to be extra careful: https://saddlebackleather.com/how-to-disinfect-leather. (FTR, I myself have sprayed tefillin straps with Lysol which I then wiped off without much apparent ill effect. Can't vouch for the effectiveness, though.  Probably safest not to have people licking tefillin straps anyway;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Loewian's link (in his comment) to clean the tefillin or find another method that you prefer.
2. For a few dollars/shekels you can buy tefilin ink or marker in your local seforim shop.  Apply when necessary. [It's more important that the straps are 100% vs. the tefillin themselves so check them regularly.][1]
3. If you need to "touch up" the tefillin or straps, first say "לשם קדושת תפלין" and then apply it [to avoid issues of kavanah in working on tefillin][1].

See shulchan aruch 33:4 and mishnah brurah 33:22 and 33:23 for #2 and #3 above.
[1]: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%92